# keras early stopping with restore_best_weights, model checkpoint with save_best_only and overfitting

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

This post is more about asking for consulting than asking for solving a problem. I'm aware of keras callbacks early stooping and model checkpoint that can prevent overfitting. When I used early stooping with `restore_best_weights=True`, then with small patience I sometimes miss the best model, and when I used checkpoint callback with `save_best_only =True` I need to do a lot of epochs. Therefore I though maybe I use early stopping with larger patience, but my problem is that the loss on my validation is very zig-zagging after some epochs (i.e., meaning it getting smaller and larger without any particular pattern).
I trying to figure out what is the best option when the validation loss is performing in this zig-zag manner.

Comment: May be you didn't create `validation` set properly. It should not be zig-zag.

Comment: @AbhilashAwasthi , my sets were created by randomly splitting a big set that i got. I meaning that after a certain point is start to zig-zag

Comment: You can use `ModelCheckPoint` to save model after each `epoch`. And then finally use the best epoch model.

Comment: Also can you post the `plot` for your training and validation loss..which depicts the zig-zag pattern. Put more information in your post like `code` and way you are training like the `callbacks` etc.

Answer (score 1):

A "zig/zag' pattern is not that unusual for the validation loss. What is important is that on average the loss decreases. This variation can be reduced by using an adjustable learning rate. The callback ReduceLROnPlateau provides this capability. Documentation is [here.](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/reduce_lr_on_plateau/). Set it up to monitor validation loss, then specify the factor parameter (I typically use .5), the patience parameter (I typically use 1) and mode='min'. I am not a fan of Early Stopping because it is essentially avoiding dealing with the fact that a model is over fitting so you do not continue toward achieving the lowest validation loss.
With the ReduceLROnPlateau callback you can use a larger initial learning rate which will help your model to converge faster for the early epochs then automatically adjust the value as needed during the later epochs. Use ModelCheckpoint to monitor the validation loss and set save_best_only=True. This will save (either the weights or the whole model) for the epoch with the lowest validation loss. After training load the model or the weights from the saved file and use it to make predictions. If your training loss decreases but in the later epochs the validation loss on average is increasing your model is over fitting. Rather than avoiding that problem it is better to deal with it. There are several methods available. First the less complex your model the less it is prone to over fitting. So if you have a lot of dense layers, start out with less dense layers and less nodes. Monitor training loss. If it keeps going down your model is training correctly and will be less prone to over fit. If it does not train well add more nodes or more dense layers but after each hidden dense layer add a dropout layer. Use the value of dropout to adjust for over fitting. If that is insufficient you may want to add regularization to the dense layers. Documentation is [here.](https://keras.io/api/layers/regularizers/) Hope this helps.